# How do I upgrade a 15.10 Wily Werewolf machine directly to 16.10 Yakkety Yak?

Tags: system-installation, upgrade

My Ubuntu 15.10 system only reminds me to install Ubuntu 16.04, but I wish to install 16.10 version.

How could I upgrade to 16.10 directly?

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` this will do the job.

Comment: Please note that the `-d` switch means that you are offered *developmental* releases which are not released yet as well. Ubuntu 16.10 has already been released, so `do-release-upgrade -d` will probably offer you the work-in-progress Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Skipping a LTS release is not recommended. Better to do a fresh install of 16.10.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to upgrade to 16.04 first, and after this upgrade is completed, upgrade to 16.10.

I think possible to upgrade while skipping a version, but I wouldn't recommend doing so, as it could result in various problems after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have set in `Software and Upgrades` that you should be notified only about new LTS (Long Term Support) versions. Ubuntu 16.04 is a LTS version, Ubuntu 16.10 isn't. You can see the setting you need to check in [this blog entry](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/ubuntu-16-04-1-released/), for example.

But as others have mentioned in answers and comments to this question, you should upgrade to the LTS version 16.04 first, and then in a second step to 16.10.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo update-manager -d
```

This last command should open the Update Manager tool where you’ll need to press a shiny ‘upgrade’ button. Do comment in case you run in trouble while doing this.

Comment: Please note that the `-d` switch means that you are offered *developmental* releases which are not released yet as well. Ubuntu 16.10 has already been released, so `do-release-upgrade -d` will probably offer you the work-in-progress Ubuntu 17.04.